# error message in discord bot(discord.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm working with discord.js but made the mistake of working in notepad, now I'm getting internal errors when I run the following:

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
if (message.content == "help") {
    message.channel.send({embed: {
    color: 0,
    title: "Commands:",
    fields: [
    { name: "Commands", value: "help /support: \n help /games: \n help /commands:", inline: true},
    { name: "Actions", value: "Need help? Don't worry! \n Play a fun game or two. \n Need help with the basics? No problem.", inline: true}]}
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

The error is:

```
index.js:64
});


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)←[39m
←[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1025:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1059:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you got confused with your closing brackets / curly brackets... seems you missed to close the if-loop body?!
Do a cleaner way to indent your code to avoid such mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @suther already mentioned your syntax was not right. Have a look at this. You have missed some curly brackets.

Maybe you should also use the strict equality comparison operator `===` instead of `==` in js, for an equality check, but it's not mandatory in that case:

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === "help") {
    message.channel.send({
      embed: {
        color: 0,
        title: "Commands:",
        fields: [
          { 
            name: "Commands", 
            value: "help /support: \n help /games: \n help /commands:", 
            inline: true 
          },
          { 
            name: "Actions", 
            value: "Need help? Don't worry! \n Play a fun game or two. \n Need help with the basics? No problem.", 
            inline: true 
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: tysm for the help